# How to run Two Wordpress blogs with different themes and with single database and same content

Tags: plugins, multisite, database

How do you run two Wordpress blogs with different themes using one database where the content remains the same in both sites? The issue that I am getting is at the Domain mapping in both blogs.

Comment: If you have multisite installed as per your question tag? then this should work just like what your asking. If multisite is not working can you be clearer on the issue and provide an example?

Comment: @Aryan Please use same name for the theme then you can see the different theme in different domain like if your site on domain1 have active theme is theme1 then change the domain2 active theme name to theme one there are 2-3 steps you need to perform to change the theme name

Comment: How can I customize the post status

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WP Multisite: load content from site X on site Y](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65560/wp-multisite-load-content-from-site-x-on-site-y)

Comment: More solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523635/two-wordpress-sites-using-diiferent-themes-on-the-same-database

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to explain how it might be done, but not sure it will work:

1. Install 2nd website with single db (2 copies).
2. Create new table in your db. Call it `wp_options2` and copy everything from `wp_options` into the new table
3. in second install in `wp-config.php`, before `if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )` add

   ```
   define( 'M7_OPTIONS_TABLE', 'wp_options2' );
   ```
4. in second install go to `wp-includes/wp-db.php` on line 1054(for WP 5.6) and add this code:

   ```
   if ( isset( $tables['options'] ) && defined( 'M7_OPTIONS_TABLE' ) )
       $tables['options'] = M7_OPTIONS_TABLE;
   ```

   (This code should be added to the `public function tables` function, before `if ( isset( $tables['users'] ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE' ) )` )

Now you should be able to change the theme, plugins atc. for the second theme, but all posts, taxonomies etc. will be doubled in both websites (wich is bad for seo btw.)

Should you run into problems with links on your second install, add:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://seccond_website.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://seccond_website.com');
```

in your `wp-config.php` file .....

**but it wouldn't solve the problem if you were to create some post on the 1-st website, on the second website it would link to the first website...**

I'll still post this answer, even though it's not correct (because of the problem described above).

As a solution you could create 2 separate installs with different `$table_prefix` and add an action to each move (save_post, save_taxonomies, save_postmeta etc.) to save from 1 db to the other, but changing the necessary links.

Or you could create a cron job on the second install to parse every post, page etc from the 1-st db to the 2-nd (since you have the access to both of them, it would be easy)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will be enough but this two plugins should give you most of what you want
[Any hostname](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/any-hostname/) - change the content urls to reflect the domain in which the content was requested
[Domain Theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/domain-theme/) - change the them according to the domain name.

I haven't tested any of them but it looks like even if they don't work you can get useful pieces of code from them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate WordPress installations (one per domain), you can define `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` in `wp-config.php` to force a specific address/hostname. Add this code to each `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

And change example.com to the name of the domain in question.

Answer (score 0):

Let me repeat your question in my words: you want two wordpress sites, using the same database and the same content. Just having a different theme and a different domain name?

That's duplicate content an google will rank both your sites badly for doing so.

I highly encourage you not to do so.

If you just want to share parts. Have a look at the `switch_to_blog()` function provided by WordPress multisite.

Comment: This answer was understandably downvoted. I upvoted it, bringing it back to a score of zero. Not because of the opinion expressed on what and what not to do, but because `switch_to_blog()` is useful information on where to start when attempting to share some content between sites. A couple of other useful puzzle pieces might be the filters `plugins_loaded` and `template_include`.

Comment: Thank you, yeah, todays me would probably give a way better answer. 6 1/2 years ago I was a WordPress rookie compared to today.

Though my point "dont't do it, google doesn't like it" is still valid, more than ever.

Unless someone has a precise plan of how to prevent this, it's still not a good idea to display content multiple times, no matter if the design changes or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme based on the current domain like

```
function select_theme( $current_theme ) {
    if ( 'domain1.com' === $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
        return 'domain1 theme name';
    } else {
        return 'domain2 theme name';
    }
}

add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'select_theme' );
add_filter( 'template', 'select_theme' );
```