# Wordpress multisite and one database

Tags: multisite, database, sharing

i need to use one database (i mean the same tables) with all sites under my network. I know about switching blog, but it's not good with wp-admin side (for example for custom post type i can't see the list of posts, only on one site in the network).

How to share all "main" tables with all sites? Is there any way?

Comment: A multisite installation already uses a single database for the entire install, perhaps you should reword your question as I suspect what you actually mean is you want the admin area to show both the current site and the root sites posts.

Comment: This also indicates the XY problem, that this is not the actual problem you're trying to solve, perhaps if you explained why you want to do this or what lead you to this, we can provide a better solution

Comment: i know that wp use one db, but i need to use the same wp_posts (wp_1_posts i guess) for all sites in the network (may be i will need to share another tables, not only wp_posts). i need this to manage my custom posts from every admin-console

Comment: So every site on the instance has the same identical posts? I still think that this is not your problem but an attempt to fix the solution to your actual problem. You've not explained why you need to do this, or why every site has identical posts =s

Comment: Quoting from http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network -- "If you plan on creating sites that are strongly interconnected, that **share data**, or share users, then a multisite network might not be the best solution." [emphasis added] You may want to reconsider whether or not you *need* a Multisite network.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP Multisite: load content from site X on site Y](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65560/wp-multisite-load-content-from-site-x-on-site-y)