# Multiple sites/domains on one database

Tags: installation

I looked through the questions and answers but could not find a specific answer that matched my question 100%.

I have developed many themes/child-themes/plugins/etc for a long time. I know my way around most WP related stuff. But now I'm a bit stuck with a challenge here.

What I want to acheive is:

1. Have 2 different domains
2. Both sites share the same theme
3. Both sites share the same posts/news, but some post only appear on the other (categories, perhaps)
4. Both sites share 'some' of the content.

2 sites, same db, different contact details, different logos, all content more or less the same except for like the footer and contact details.

How is this done in the easiest way?

Comment: Don't use multisite or two separate WordPress sites for this.

Comment: Why? What should I do then?

Comment: It seems like what you want should run on the same site, but use coding to achieve what you want. The question is a bit localized in its current state, perhaps you could decide exactly what you want, and ask questions on specifically what you want to do, preferably with what you have tried to far

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I think this question is very clear and I have the same one. This would be matching up with the functionality of Drupal's Domain Access module https://www.drupal.org/project/domain - but for wordpress

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WP Multisite: load content from site X on site Y](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65560/wp-multisite-load-content-from-site-x-on-site-y)